# JS async queue with return data

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, google-api, queue

I want to make asynchronous requests to the google api and save the results in one array. My attempts to somehow return a value from the apiHandler have failed. I can't figure uot where I need to grab thsi data. Can you help me?

I'm not very experienced with js, much less asynchronous js.

```
import { queue } from "async";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

let concurrency = 10; // How many async processes will be running
let KEY = '';
let ids = [
    'sMTs5bvAsGA',
    'kW5X4dU0gnY',
    'dX2hyyKFIHA',
    '91egEkKuVas',
    'DfhKbYXRu6Q',
    'hQdOqC-1tVg',
    'AOwFmabnb7s',
];

let data = [];

export const taskQueue = queue(async (task, done) => {
    try {
        let data = await task();
        done;
        return data;
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
}, concurrency);

taskQueue.drain(() => {
    console.log("All items completed!\n");
    process.exit();
});

export function getItems(video_ids) {
    video_ids.forEach((id) => {
        taskQueue.push(() =>
            apiHandler(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&relatedToVideo=${id}&maxResults=50&type=video&key=${KEY}`),

            (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    throw new Error('Error getting data.');
                }
            })
    });
};

async function apiHandler(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
}

getItems(ids);
```

P.S Different implementation

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";

let concurrency = 10; // How many async processes will be running
let KEY = '';
let video_ids = [
    'sMTs5bvAsGA',
    'kW5X4dU0gnY',
    'dX2hyyKFIHA',
    '91egEkKuVas',
    'DfhKbYXRu6Q',
    'hQdOqC-1tVg',
    'AOwFmabnb7s',
];

let data = [];
let promises = [];

function apiHandler(url) {
    return fetch(url).then((response) => {
        data.push(response.json);
    });
}

video_ids.forEach((id) => {
    promises.push(() =>
        apiHandler(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&relatedToVideo=${id}&maxResults=50&type=video&key=${KEY}`),

        (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                throw new Error('Error getting data.');
            }
        })
});

Promise.all(promises).then((response) => {
    console.log(data)
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `done()` and not `done`?

Comment: Your api handler returns nothing. You are pushing a function to an array?

Comment: @Konrad, If I change it to done(), this code will throw exception "done is not a function"

Comment: @epascarello, I deleted return line

Comment: I ran your code and it works fine for me

Comment: `} catch (err) {  throw err;  }`  Pointless code block.   Also,are you mixing up versions of `async` here, as done doesn't appears to be a callback param.

Comment: Do you really need to use queue. Simple for loop of map with promise all settled can do this.

Comment: @epascarello   He possibly needs the concurrency option.   Of course in his example it's not doing anything with just 7 id's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your problem it seems that it makes sense to build an array of `Promise` elements and then call `.all()`.

A `Promise` is an object which can be resolved or rejected. Assuming that your `fetch` is a promise, you can do the following:

## 1. Create an empty array

Somewhere you need to create an empty array that will have to be accessed in the relevant places of your algorithm. For the sake of simplicity, I will create it as a variable:

```
let promises = [];
```

## 2. Make sure `apiHandler` returns a promise

```
function apiHandler(url) {
    return fetch(url).then((response) => {
        data.push(response);
    });
}
```

## 3. At your loop hydrate your promise array

```
    video_ids.forEach((id) => {
        promises.push(
            apiHandler(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&relatedToVideo=${id}&maxResults=50&type=video&key=${KEY}`)
        )
    });
```

## 4. Somewhere, possibly just after your loop, create an .all() handler

```
Promise.all(promises).then((response) => {
    //do something
});
```

## Explanation

The `.then()` and `.all()` calls also create promises and you pass an array of promises to `.all()`, so its `.then()` will be called when all promises were fulfilled. As about `promises`, it was built of the `.then()` handlers of your `fetch` calls.

EDIT

Proof-of-concept

```js
let data = [];
let promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(function() {
         data.push(i);
         resolve(i);
    }, i * 100)));
};
console.log('FIRST OUTPUT ' + JSON.stringify(data)); //empty
Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    console.log('THIRD OUTPUT ' + JSON.stringify(data));
});
console.log('SECOND OUTPUT ' + JSON.stringify(data)); //empty
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the code creates a list of promises in which apiHandler is executed. When we get a response from the server, we write the data to the "data" array. The last piece of code is executed only when we get results from all of them, right? Maybe I'm dumb, but it only outputs an empty "data" array. `Promise.all(promises).then((response) => {
    console.log(data);
});`

Comment: @wineT you understood it correctly, but I suppose there was a mistake in the implementation. Can you edit your question and append your current try?

Comment: @wineT please let me know here in the comment section if you have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I added new implementation

Comment: @wineT you are correct, there is something wrong in my initial answer. While figuring out, I have added a proof-of-concept to show that the idea works. Will add a further edit soon.

Comment: @wineT made a further edit, basically my mistake in the initial answer was that I added a function wrapped around a promise rather than the promise itself to `promises`. I have added a fix for that as well.